# I get 'page not found' error with Codeigniter and AJAX request

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, jquery, controller

I'm developing a project with CodeIgniter but i have a problem when sending request with jQuery AJAX. My default controller is:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "test";
```

and here is my test controller:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class test extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function login_with() {
        echo "1";
    }
}
```

and here is my AJAX request:

```
$(function() {
    $('#login_with').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?= base_url('test/login_with') ?>",
            data:"login=1",
            success:function(ajax_success){
                alert(ajax_success);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

finally here is my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

What is wrong here? I'm getting 404 page not found error when request has been sent.

Comment: Where did you put your ajax code. In what file??

Comment: I usually just do it like this: `url  :  '/test/login_with'` and always works.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `site_url()` like

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?= site_url('test/login_with'); ?>",
        data:"login=1",
        success:function(ajax_success){
            alert(ajax_success);
        }
    });
```

And try to put exit after echo like

```
public function login_with() {
    echo "1";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: What your console redirecting url..??

Comment: @Gautam3164 the login_with() method is not really the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

First check if your website has `mod_rewrite` enabled then
check if you have this in your config/config.php

`$config['index_page'] = ''`

i suggest you to try this htaccess then:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: No need to echo if it is like <?= site_url();?>

Comment: oh ok always not using short cuts :/ sorry eheh

Comment: yeah its not necessary when i use <?= shot tag :) problem still same. you can check live it here; http://www.pvpranks.com/uzuntweet/

Comment: but dude.... http://pvpranks.com/uzuntweet/twitter_baglan this is not what you posted here :P @OnurŞevik

Comment: yes i've changed the function names. Names aren't important here now just why it doesn't exec function

Comment: @OnurŞevik ok ;) are you sure your server is supporting/enabled mod_rewrite?

Comment: @OnurŞevik i also see strange new page here http://www.pvpranks.com/uzuntweet/index.php/ the index.php should be run by Codeigniter in that root

Comment: that's my other project. Then .htaccess of this project affects this project, i uploaded project to server for show you the error normally im working on localhost. But failed.

Comment: @OnurŞevik so strange i think you should keep wesites separated or you'll get troubles there actually dunno )

Comment: yes you're right. but it doesn't works on localhost too. Can't find a solve :/

Comment: i solved the problem :) on localhost my mod rewrite settings was wrong and i changed them :) Thanks for helps.

Comment: @OnurŞevik you're welcome if you feel good with my answer please accept it and good luck dude! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $('#login_with').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: window.location.origin+"/test/login_with",
            data:"login=1",
            success:function(ajax_success){
                alert(ajax_success);
            }
        });
    });
});
```